# Append function results to file

Tags: python, list, ascii

I am trying to run a function that returns two values, on a range of number, and to store the returned values into a ASCII.txt file.

My code is this:

```
site = np.genfromtxt('...\Plot_1.txt', dtype=None, delimiter='\t')

def process(matrix, kernel_size, kernel_dilation, kernel_zs, kernel_norm, local_chm, threshold_value):
    ker_size = kernel_size
    ker_bx = 0
    ker_by = 0
    ker_a = kernel_dilation
    ker_zs = kernel_zs
    ker_norm = kernel_norm
    loc_chm = local_chm
    th_value = threshold_value        

    return ker_size, nr_trees #both are float numbers

for i in range(1, 6, 2):
    list = []
    a = process(site, 5, i, 2, 1, 2, 0.9) #This is the function, only returns two values
    print a, type(a), np.shape(a)
    list.append(a)
    print list
    with open('E:\Test_matrix_automatic.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write(list)
```

It gives the error:

> TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

I don't know how to fix this. I haven't used functions that return two values.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are referring at. I am a beginner at programming.

Comment: What is `site` in your code and where is it defined?

Comment: Stacktrace is the full error; not just the one line. It shows the context where the error occurred.

Comment: Print the full error message Python shows you, with everything it prints.

Comment: You can't write a *list* to file. You can only write `str` objects (and the like) to file. You'll have to convert the list to a string first.

Comment: 'site' is a matrix that I read from an ASCII file

Comment: @ Wilelm Van Onsem: That is the only error I get: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Master_I/GIS/Python/Wavelets/Test_Conv_Automatic.py", line 260, in <module>
    outfile.write(list)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a tuple of floats from process() and are appending it to list.
As the error message states, the write()-method of file objects needs a string or a character buffer object, but you're handing it a list, which contains tuples of floats.
You should convert the list to a string before printing it.

You could try something like this:

```
with open('E:\Test_matrix_automatic.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    for item in list:
        outfile.write(str(item) + '\n')
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I only need to make it not print the brackets in the file (ex: '(5, 0)'), but it's enough for here. :)